# C++ define alias for a struct using template

Tags: c++, templates, struct

using c++ language : i made a structure generic and i want to give it an alias but failed !
here is the code:

```
template<class T>
struct noeud {
    T val;
    struct noeud *next;

};
typedef struct noeud * Noeud;
```

here is the error:

template argument required for 'struct noeud'
invalid type in declaration before ';' token
Build : 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Comment: It's a template, not a type. You can't define a type alias for something which is not *yet* a type.

Comment: You don't need struct keyword neither typedef in C++ for what you are doing.

Comment: @Davidbrcz no typedef? and how would you create an alias then?

Comment: @Niklas R. You dont, a least in C++03. Moreover, he is typedefing a struct like C programmers usually do. Pretty pointless there. Here you don't need a typedef on template. May be on a type within the linked list if he doesn't improve the design of noeud (which should be nested into template a linked list class and not templated itself).

Answer (score 4):

you can achieve this by using a syntax introduced in the C++11 revision :

```
template<class T>
struct Node;

template <class T>
using NodePtr = Node<T>*;
```

You should stay away from naked pointer and use a smart pointer instead, like `unique_ptr` :

```
template <class T>
using NodePtr = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>;
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
typedef struct noeud<your type>* Noeud;
```

where your type is the type you want the struct to be instanciated with

Comment: thanks for the answer but is it possible to do like :
typedef struct noeud<T> * Noeud;
i want this alias to be generic at the end i will do like that for new type (example : int):
Noeud<int> my_variable;

Comment: The question ask for a template alias and it is not possible with typedef.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have another template as an alias you have to use the `using` keyword:

```
template<typename T>
using AliasName = noeud<T>*;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but is it possible to do like : 
typedef struct noeud<T> * Noeud; 
i want this alias to be generic at the end i will do like that for new type (example : int): 
Noeud<int> my_variable;

Comment: C++11 is required and the syntax in wrong. The good one is `template<typename T> using AliasName= noeud<T>* ;`

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers:

- The class `noeud` is a template and thus it needs a template parameter to become a type as template types are deduced at compile time. E.g.:

  ```
  template<class T>
  struct noeud {
      T val;
      //noeud* next          // Error: compiler doesn't know what a noeud is.
      noeud<T>* next;        // Need to specify template parameter (T can be used).
  };

  typedef noeud<int>* Noeud; // Need to specify template parameter.
  ```

  Also in C++ you don't have to put the keyword `struct` in front of the type when declaring "structs"/aggregate classes when there is no ambiguity. In C++ the keyword `struct` means **class** with default access specifier set to *public*.
- As mentioned by others, in **C++11** you can use the `using` syntax to declare a templated alias (`typedef` does *not* allow templated aliases), e.g.:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  using noeud<T>* Noeud; // Use 'using' to create an alias in same manner as typedef.
  ```

  This allows you to use the alias as:

  ```
  Noeud<int> n; // Type is: noeud<int>*
  ```